# IconRightWidget in the wrong place

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm coding a book reader app with kivymd. I tryied making a MDList with the avaliable chapters and a button to download in every ListItem.

This is a piece of my code:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import IconRightWidget

class Library(Screen):
    pass
class Book(Screen):
    pass
class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass
KV = '''
SM:
    Library:
    Book:
<Library>:
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "book"
            app.list_chapters()

<Book>:
    name: "book"
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: chap
                
'''
class Aplication(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.chaps = True
        return screen
        

    def list_chapters(self):
        if self.chaps: 
            for chap in range(0, 11):
                chapter = TwoLineListItem(text= f'Chapter {chap}')
                
                rightIcon = IconRightWidget(icon="arrow-down-circle-outline")
                self.root.get_screen("book").ids.chap.add_widget(chapter)
                chapter.add_widget(rightIcon)
        self.chaps = False
Aplication().run()
```

For some reason, all of the `IconRightWidget` Buttons are getting in the corner of the last `TwoListItem`. What should I do?

Comment: Try using `TwoLineAvatarIconListItem` instead.

Comment: Or use `TwoLineRightIconListItem`.